# Specify nodeport when creating deployment in Minikube

Tags: docker, minikube

This requirement is primarily for a development environment.

As I update a docker image using which a deployment is created and exposed through Minikube, I have to delete and re-create this deployment and service.
However, I'd like to maintain the same nodeport that was assigned to that particular service. I know that if left to Minikube, a random port is assigned. But can I specify the NodePort?

I create the deployment using the following Yaml file and expose the service through the `expose` command.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: dpl_name
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app_name
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ctr_name
        image: 192.168.42.22:80/imagename:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8090
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/containerdata
          name: vlm
      volumes:
        - name: vlm
          hostPath:
            path: '/data/vlm'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose the deployment by creating a [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/) of type NodePort and specifying the `nodePort` value in that .yaml configuration:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app_name
  labels:
    app: app_name
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8090
    nodePort: 30000 # <--
  selector:
    app: app_name
```

This will specify to always use the `nodePort` value: `30000`

Comment: Thanks. It works. Accepting this as the answer. I do however have a couple of follow up questions: What is the "port" for? If I understand correctly targetport tells the service where to forward the requests (which should be same as the container ports), but I don't get "port"? 2nd question: I tried accessing the service by its VIP and port from inside the cluster and it works, but I can't do that with its name. Is there something else I need to add? I need to do that so that if I change environment, I can continue using the name even if the VIP changes.