# Connecting to NodePort Minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I created a Service and a Deployment but I am unable to access the service with `minikube service --url accounts-service` or `minikube service accounts-service`.

While the second one opens the browser but never connects, the first one just remains in my terminal.

Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: accounts-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: accounts-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: accounts-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: accounts-service
          image: xxxx:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3001
```

Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: accounts-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: accounts-service
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3001
  type: NodePort
```

I don't know why my Minikube is not connecting to the Port. I am using minkube with Docker

Comment: What port is the process inside the container listening on?  If you run the same image with `docker run`, does it answer requests?

Comment: What is OS did you use? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Here is a very [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896718/specify-nodeport-when-creating-deployment-in-minikube) I think it might suit you. This is described in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).